# How to connect an Office addin to a server?

Tags: node.js, ms-office, mean-stack, office-js

It seems that most of Office addins don't have a server or a database.
But it seems that some addins do have a server behind.

I have built websites by `mean-stack`.
And we can indeed use `angularjs` to build front-end of an Office addin.

How can I connect the front-end of an Office addin to a (mongo + express + node) server?

Comment: You write front-end code that communicates using whatever client libraries?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question...

Comment: What is your question? How to write an office add-in or how to write the code to talk to Mongo/Node server?

Comment: how to write the code to talk to Mongo/Node server...

Comment: Okay, and what does that have to do with Office? Using what programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [**Office Add-ins overview**](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) (with emphasis)

> #### What can an Office Add-in do?
>
> An Office Add-in can do almost anything a webpage can do inside the browser, such as the following:
>
> - Extend Office native UI by creating custom ribbon buttons and tabs.
> - Provide an interactive UI and custom logic through HTML and JavaScript.
> - **Use JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery, Angular, and many others**.
> - **Connect to REST endpoints and web services via HTTP and AJAX**.

So, use a favorite framework of your choice.

You are familiar with MEAN stack, so use Angular, or Mongoose, or any other Javascript MongoDB client **in the add-in** to connect to your server just like you would from any other front-end webpage.

Bonus: [Add-in with Angular 2](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2)

Comment: For example, in my `mean-stack` website, I have `package.json`, `app.js`, `index.html`, `www`, etc. Then I use `npm start` to start the server. So I just need to upload such a `index.html` to the office? it will be able to talk to the server automatically, right?

Comment: Automatically? Probably not, no. You need to at the very least give the URL of the remote server. The add-in is not responsible for running the entire MEAN stack. Just the **A** part.

Comment: For an website, once the server is started, `https://www.example.com/#/home` in a browser will load the page. But for an office addin, I will not use `ui-router` and should upload a `index.html` that could talk to the server, right?

Comment: I'm not an office developer. Can't answer that. Your question was "how to communicate with server," and as far as I can tell, the answer is "with Javascript"

Comment: @SoftTimur You probably didn't read resource provided through. Please look at the section [Anatomy of an Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#anatomy-of-an-office-add-in). This section explains two main parts of the Office Add-in: one - manifest which will have references to your second part - web app. What technology for your WebApp you are choose to use is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

> How to connect an office addin to a server?

The connection point of your Web Application to the Office is the Manifest file. Please see more on [Anatomy of an Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#anatomy-of-an-office-add-in). Your web application is required to communicate with the Office itself, so you would need to include Office.js lib and initialize it before run any other functions on the client.